# Regex replace one value between comma separated values

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having a bunch of comma separated CSV files.
I would like to replace exact one value which is between the third and fourth comma. I would love to do this with Notepad++ 'Find in Files' and Replace functionality which could use RegEx.

Each line in the files look like this:

```
03/11/2016,07:44:09,327575757,1,5434543,...
```

The value I would like to replace in each line is always the number 1 to another one.

It can't be a simple regex for e.g. `,1,` as this could be somewhere else in the line, so it must be the one after the third and before the fourth comma...

Could anyone help me with the RegEx?
Thanks in advance!

Two more rows as example:

01/25/2016,15:22:55,276575950,1,103116561,10.111.0.111,ngd.itemversions,0.401,0.058,W10,0.052,143783065,,...
01/25/2016,15:23:07,276581704,1,126731239,10.111.0.111,ll.browse,7.133,1.589,W272,3.191,113273232,,...

Comment: Could you please add 1 more sample with expected output showing with `1` must be replaced and which not? Also, try `^(?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*\K,1,`

Comment: I suggest you do this with `R`. Much easier, safer, faster!: http://r-project.org

Comment: Two more rows as example:
01/25/2016,15:22:55,276575950,1,103116561,10.111.0.111,ngd.itemversions,0.401,0.058,W10,0.052,143783065,,
01/25/2016,15:23:07,276581704,1,126731239,10.111.0.111,ll.browse,7.133,1.589,W272,3.191,113273232,,

Where (this time) the 1 after 3rd comma must be replaced

Comment: If my approach works best, I will post an answer. Does it?

Comment: Yes, I think it fits well (even I'm still testing :)

Comment: To make sure the regex does not flow onto another line, you need to add `\n` to the negated character classes: `^(?:[^,\n]*,){2}[^,\n]*\K,1,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[^,\n]*,){2}[^,\n]*\K,1,
```

Replace with any value you need.

The pattern explanation:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:[^,\n]*,){2}` - 2 sequences of

  - `[^,\n]*` - zero or more characters other than `,` and `\n` (matched with the negated character class `[^,\n]`) followed with
  - `,` - a literal comma
- `[^,\n]*` - zero or more characters other than `,` and `\n`
- `\K` - an operator that forces the regex engine to discard the whole text matched so far with the regex pattern
- `,1,` - what we get in the match.

[image]

Note that `\n` inside the negated character classes will prevent overflowing to the next lines in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace value between third and fourth comma using following regex.

**Regex:** `([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+),([^,]+)`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `\1,value`. I used `XX` for demo.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ6mZ4/3)**

**Notepad++ Demo**

[image: Notepad++ Demo.]

Comment: The rightmost pair of brackets can be omitted as `\2` is not needed. The belt and braces approach would add a final `,` to both search (giving `([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+),[^,]+,` and replace (`\1,value,`).

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Ah yea true that. I left it by mistake after testing. I will add a note.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see, but this iterates me then through the line, ignoring that it should start in the new line then.

Comment: You might also add a start of line anchor `^([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+),[^,]+,`.

Comment: @alexko: Checkout the demo I added.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Seems to be working okay without `^` in notepad++. Am I missing something ?

Comment: But ^([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+),[^,]+, selects me the whole first part of the line up including the third comma (so 03/11/2016,07:44:09,327575757,)

Comment: @alexko: Yes, check out the replacement part. Include `,` in replacement string too.

Comment: Try the line `01/25/2016,15:23:07,276581704,4,1,126731239` where the `1` is between the 4th and 5th commas. The question says *"after the third and before the fourth comma"*.